# What is the right syntax for this joined EF Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to get a query that returns everything properly formatted for my ViewModel so I do not have to manually copy everything over from my entity models. I have this Linq query that is giving me an error. :

```
var query = from i in context.Invoices 
            join l in context.LineItems on i.InvoiceID equals l.InvoiceID into il
            where i.InvoiceID == id
            select new InvoiceViewModel()
                {
                InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID,
                CustomerID = i.CustomerID,
                InvoiceNote = i.Note,
                InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate,
                Terms = i.Terms,
                LineItems = il.ToList<LineItemViewModel>()
                };
```

This is my ViewModel

```
 public class InvoiceViewModel        {
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNote { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LineItemViewModel> LineItems { get; set; }
    }

public class LineItemViewModel        {
    public int LineItemID { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string LineItemNote { get; set; }
    }
```

The error I am getting is (the red squigly is under the il in LineItems = il.ToList())

```
'IEnumerable<LineItem>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList<LineItemViewModel>(IEnumerable<LineItemViewModel>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<LineItemViewModel>'
```

Which I (sorta, kinda, a little) understand. So what is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: `LineItems = il.select new LineItemViewModel() { LineItemID = il.LineItemID, etc }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly initialize your `LineItemViewModel` instances from the `LineItem` entities. You might be better off writing this as a correlated subquery rather than a join:

```
var query = 
        from i in context.Invoices 
        where i.InvoiceID == id
        select new InvoiceViewModel()
        {
            InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID,
            CustomerID = i.CustomerID,
            InvoiceNote = i.Note,
            InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate,
            Terms = i.Terms,
            LineItems = 
            (
                from li in context.LineItems
                where li.InvoiceID == i.InvoiceID
                select new LineItemViewModel
                {
                    LineItemID = li.LineItemID, 
                    InvoiceID = li.InvoiceID,
                    Quantity = li.Quantity,
                    Item = li.Item,
                    Amount = li.Amount,
                    LineItemNote = li.LineItemNote,
                }
            ).ToList()
        };
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I am a longtime SQL guy (back to dBase II) and this Linq and model stuff is taking twice as long to learn because I have so much to unlearn first.

Comment: @BradMathews: There's a learning curve, but I find it pays off because LINQ takes advantage of the strong typing features of C#, giving you compile-time type checking and IntelliSense better than T-SQL could. If you wanted to simplify your code (at the cost of sacrificing some tier separation), you could avoiding using view models and project the data models directly.

Comment: From what I have learned so far, it is simpler on the backend to use the data models directly, but I have to say I have fallen in love with view models due to the added simplicity and power on the front end. Gaining competence with Linq will be a key to connecting it all and you have helped me with that. Thanks.